# Adding elements to the XML file

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I need to add more "Artwork" elements to this XML file with the same title,media,desription,created and display child elements, I tried using the max0ccurs=unbounded but saw that i can only use that if the elements are not directly related to the global element.
This is the XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Artworks">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Artwork"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Artwork">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Media" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Created" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Display" type="xs:string"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the XML

```
<Artworks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="artwork1.xsd">
    <Artwork>
        <Title>Xtreme Air</Title>
        <Media>Glass Sculpture</Media>
        <Description>An amazing work that uses glass balloon shaps to illustrate a rainbow of balloons circuling a glass earth.</Description>
        <Created>April 2010</Created>
        <Display>Orlando Museum of Arts</Display>
        <Artwork></Artwork>

   </Artwork>

</Artworks>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on the element usage definition in the first template:

```
<xs:element name="Artworks">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Artwork" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

Now you can have unlimited `Artwork` children in your `Artworks` element (but not recursive).

Comment: I did that before... but i just took a look at it again i was placing the new elements before the first closing xml tag...  but thanks anyway much appreciated just a bit frustrated i guess